# Añadir Botón de barra de navegación en Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Estoy intentando crear un BottomNavigationBar, el problema es que si se insertan 3 botones si aparece el nombre del botón, pero al intenat  acomomdar 4 o mas botones en la barra deja de aparecer el nombre. El objetivo es que al acomodar 4 o mas botones en barra, aparezca el nombre del boton/icono.

Por ejemplo con tres botones en Barra:
[image: BottomNavigationBar con tres botones]

Con 4 botones en Barra
[image: BottomNavigationBar con cuatro botones]

Adjunto codigo

```
 class _BotonBarraNavegacionState extends State<BotonBarraNavegacion> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;

  List<Widget> _widgetOptions = <Widget>[
    BotonInicio(),
    Favorito(),
    ProfilePage(),
    Add(),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        showSelectedLabels: true,
        showUnselectedLabels: false,
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.home,
              color: Colors.blue,
              size: 30,
            ),
            title: Text('Inicio'),
            activeIcon: Icon(
              Icons.home,
              color: Colors.red,
              size: 30,
            ),
          ),
         ....
         
        ],
        onTap: (index) {
          setState(() {
            _selectedIndex = index;
          });
        },
      ),
      body: _widgetOptions.elementAt(_selectedIndex),
    );
  }

}




 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para que se muestre el texto correctamente, **usa la propiedad `label` en cada uno de tus `BottomNavigationBarItem`, de hecho la propiedad `title` es obsoleta y no deberías usarla, ahora debes usar `label` ya que permite una escala de texto mejorada.**

```
   BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(
          Icons.home,
          color: Colors.blue,
          size: 30,
        ),
        //title: Text('Inicio'),
        activeIcon: Icon(
          Icons.home,
          color: Colors.red,
          size: 30,
        ),
        label: 'Inicio',
      ),
      ...
      ...
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si ahora deseas que se muestren los textos de los iconos al mismo tiempo usa la propiedad type: `BottomNavigationBarType.fixed` en tu `BottomNavigationBar`:

```
BottomNavigationBar(
    type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed, 
    ...
    ...
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Cierto, la propiedad title es obsoleta, debemos usar label. Gracias

Answer (score 1):

El `bottomNavigationBar` tiene una propiedad que te permite arreglar o escoger el tipo que quieres que sea la barra de navegación, entre estas propiedades esta `BottomNavigationBarType.fixed`, coloca eso dentro del Widget y debería aparecerte el nombre del botón:

```
BottomNavigationBar(
    type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed, //Agregar esta línea
    currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
    showSelectedLabels: true,
    showUnselectedLabels: false,
    items: [
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(
          Icons.home,
          color: Colors.blue,
          size: 30,
        ),
        title: Text('Inicio'),
        activeIcon: Icon(
          Icons.home,
          color: Colors.red,
          size: 30,
        ),
      ),
     ....
     
    ],
    onTap: (index) {
      setState(() {
        _selectedIndex = index;
      });
    },
  ),
```

Comment: Funciono, Gracias